# what is the distribution of $\max\{A+C,A+D,B+C,B+D\}$, given A,B,C,D are i.i.d following distribution $f(x)$?

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics

Given $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ are i.i.d following distribution $f(x)$,
what is the distribution of $\max\{A+C,A+D,B+C,B+D\}$,?
Though $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ are i.i.d but $\{A+C,A+D,B+C,B+D\}$ are correlated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: for any four real numbers $a,b,c,d$, $\max(a+c,a+d,b+c,b+d)$ = $\max(a,b)+\max(c,d)$.

Comment: To add to whuber's hint, $\max(A,B)$ and $\max(C,D)$ are _independent_ random variables, in fact i.i.d. random variables whose distribution you should determine as a first step.